# Ошибка 400 при выполнении axios запроса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nestjs

Есть функция, которая отправляет на сервер поля пользователя

```
const handleSubmit = async (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:4200/api/auth/register', JSON.stringify(FormFields))
}
```

Примерно такие

```
{"name":"Dmitry","surname":"Dmitry","email":"testemail1@gmail.com","phone":"1234567890","password":"12345678"}
```

Но при отправке выдает ошибку:

```
Request failed with status code 400
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49500:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:48191:66)
```

При этом все в порядке когда такой же запрос отправляется через insomnia[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделай дебаг, посмотри, приходит ли `FormFields`, смотри сразу как `JSON.stringify(FormFields)`. Просто выведи его в логи, если всё окей, то посмотри, может тебе нужен Bearer токен? Я знаю ситуации, когда люди и при начальной регистрации юзают токены. Глянь, может какие хэдеры есть в твоем Insomnia, которые ты должен передать при axios запросе. Код 400 - это код BAD_REQUEST, и если ты на сервере его выводил, то уж точно с сопроводным текстом, иначе HttpException в Nest.js не пускает, без этого поля. Дай больше кода, отдебажь его сам